# Getting the email address of the sender [NodeJS/Nodemailer]

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm doing an app with React/NodeJS,

In the app, there's the Contact Page with a form with 3 input fields : email, object and message,
In the email field, the user puts his email address to be contacted later by the recipient (me),
**I succeeded to send the mail and the object on my email address,but in the sender space of my Gmail I get my mail and not the mail from the input field,**

**How can I get the mail from the sender in the mail ?**

Here's my code :

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: `${process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS}`,
      pass: `${process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD}`,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: formValues.email, <-- HERE I HAVE THE MAIL OF THE SENDER, BUT CAN NEVER SEE IT IN THE EMAIL
    to: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    subject: `Contact form - ${formValues.object}`,
    text: formValues.message,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("err ", err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent" });
    }
  });
```

**You can see in the picture that instead of getting the email of the sender, I have my email in both sender and recipients**
https://ibb.co/rxNHGnP

[Nodemailer docs](https://nodemailer.com/about/)

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you trying to send an email from an account that is not yours?

Comment: I want to get the email written in the "email" input field in the sender place of the email, I can't get it in the email so I can't know who sent it

Comment: I don't think that is possible, the sender field represent the address that is trying to send the email (the one who logged in) which in this case it's you. That's why you are seeing sender as your email address as you are sending an email from yourself to yourself. You can only add the formValues data to the recipient (to) field of mailOption.

Comment: ok so I don't undersqtand the ```from``` property of ```mailOptions``` object then... make an answer and I'll accept it !

Comment: You are sending the email from your Gmail account, thus your address is the sender. Google (and probably most other mail providers) do not allow to specify an arbitrary email address as sender. You may be able to add the clients address in the `ReplyTo` field, though ...

Comment: ok but nodemailer docs mislead me because of the ```from``` property of the ```mailOptions``` object, I'll put the email of the sender in the object then

Comment: Depending on the configuration of a mail server it *might* be possible to have multiple allowed sender addresses for one account, also if you setup your own mail server you may decide to not check the sender at all ( but you must not wonder if your server gets blacklisted pretty fast) . But Gmail doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, the sender field represent the address that is trying to send the email (the one who logged in) which in this case it's you. That's why you are seeing sender as your email address as you are sending an email from yourself to yourself. You can only add the formValues data to the recipient (to) field of mailOption.